# The elif and else commands are completely ignored and instead whatever I type, even if it is random letters, I always get the answer for if

Tags: python, python-3.x

After I did the code below I checked if it worked. The problem was that whatever I typed it always shows the response of 'if' even if I changed the response

I tried changing positions and responses but nothing worked

```
hello = input ("Hello there! \n My name is PIM. \n It `enter code here` stands for Primary Interactive Machine. \n What is your name?")
print ("Nice to meet you," + hello)
ans1 = input ("Can I ask you a question? <yes/no>")
if (ans1 == 'yes',' yes')                              
    ans2 = input ("Which color do you prefer? <blue/pink>")
elif(ans1 == 'no',' no'):
    print ("Well then, we will just stay in silence")
else:
    print ("I will not talk to someone who doesn't care about me. \n You had one simple job, choose yes or no and even then, you failed.")
```

It is expected to reply accordingly to the response but instead, it only sends the 'if' reply

Comment: Hi. I didn't know that `if (ans1 == 'yes',' yes'):` was a valid python code, and I suspect it means `if ((ans1 == 'yes') or (' yes')):` and the truthy value of ' yes' is always `True`. Change it to `if(ans1 == 'yes' or ans1 == ' yes'):` or to `if (ans1 in ['yes', ' yes]):`

Comment: @Aryerez It doesn't mean `or`. It's simply a *tuple*. A *non-empty tuple*. Which will always be truthy.

Comment: @deceze Tnx for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ans1 in( 'yes' , ' yes'):                             
    ans2 = input ("Which color do you prefer? <blue/pink>")
elif ans1 in( 'no' or ' no'):
    print ("Well then, we will just stay in silence")
else:
    print ("I will not talk to someone who doesn't care about me. \n You had one simple job, choose yes or no and even then, you failed.")
```